# Select data based on certain set frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

`settings`

```
**id** ->number

**trigger_metric** -> MONTHS, WEEKS, DAYS

**trigger_frequency** -> number

**trigger_start_date** -> date
```

What I need is to select the entry based on whether it is allowed to trigger on date that or not.

So lets say for example for the following entry
`id:xxx, trigger_metric: MONTHS, trigger_frequency:1 , trigger_start_date:'2021-09-01'`

the row should be selected on the `trigger_start_date` and then every `trigger_frequency` `trigger_metric` i.e. `1 MONTHS` in this case. so it should be selected on `2021-09-01` and every 1 months after that so `2021-10-01`, `2022-11-01`

Same will be the case for `DAYS` and `WEEKS` as well.

I wrote the following query to handle this case

```
SELECT
 *
FROM settings fs
WHERE (fs.trigger_start_date = Convert(DATE, GETDATE()) OR CAST((
  CASE fs.trigger_metric
    WHEN 'MONTHS' THEN
        IIF((DATEDIFF(month, fs.trigger_start_date, GETDATE()) %
             fs.trigger_frequency) = 0 AND
            DATEPART(dd, fs.trigger_start_date) = DATEPART(dd, GETDATE())
          , 1, 0)


    WHEN 'WEEKS' THEN
      IIF(DATEDIFF(week, fs.trigger_start_date, GETDATE()) % fs.trigger_frequency =0 
          AND DATEPART(dw, fs.trigger_start_date) = DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), 1, 0)


    WHEN 'DAYS' THEN
      IIF((DATEDIFF(day, fs.trigger_start_date, GETDATE()) % fs.trigger_frequency) = 0, 1, 0)

    ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS BIT) = 1);
```

my logic here for months is that diff the two dates and see if they are at the `trigger_frequency` difference and also check and see if the date are equal. Meaning if 2 dates are `2021-09-01 and 2021-11-02` and the frequency is 2. Then the dates diff would be divisible by the frequency (2) and since the dates are not equal it would not trigger.

So this code works in most cases except for 1. So lets say the setting is set for AUGUST 31 and the frequency is 1, then since September does not have 31, the query will not work.

So my question is. Is there any way to modify this query to handle the above case that I had mentioned?

Comment: Even if there was a way to identify that a date was the end of a month (which of course there is), there's a problem with your model: What happens if we have a start date of 30 Sep? 30 Sep is the last day of the month for Sep. But does that mean it should run again on Oct 30 (same day of month) or Oct 31 (last day of the month for October)? Before being able to write the code, you're first going to have to decide on the rule.

Comment: @allmhuran If its on 30 it needs to run on 30 and if its on 31 then it should run on 31 but if 31 is not available it should run on 30th or the last day of the month (as it also need to run for feb)

Comment: Would the `EOMONTH()` function help you with this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @paneerakbari I think that would work. Ill just add one more condition for the last day of the month with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the limited purpose of determining whether a given date is the last day of a month, you could use the `EOMONTH` function. You would still need to perform other conditional checks relevant to your requirements, but this should help get around the difficulty of varying month-ends, leap days, etc.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15